# shell script for cron job

Tags: shell-script, shell, cron

I've just set-up one cron-job in cpanel, but although it seems to be executing the script it doesn't work as intended.

Here is the cron job command in cpanel:

```
/bin/sh /home/my-username/cronjobs/sedclearmalw.sh
```

and here is the content of the script :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ../public_html/
grep -rl '_0xaae8' . | xargs sed -i 's/var\s_0xaae8.*//g'
```

I believe the cd command should be correct, as it needs to go back a directory and then enter public_html, however the second command seems to be the problem.
I have tried running it via ssh, (bash sedclearmalw.sh) it seems like it's running for ~15 seconds but it's not doing its job , as i checked with the following command :

```
grep -rl '_0xaae8'
```

and it returns 1 file containing _0xaae8.
Any help will be appreciated, it must be something simple as i know the above command in the shell script works all right when executed via ssh (not through the script).

Comment: Specify the absolute path to the `cd` in the first line. The time taken is high because you are using `grep -rl` and the default cron job directory could be `/`  , and hence it is searching everywhere.

Comment: I will try that, do you maybe know why the grep command doesnt work when i execute it via script (ex. bash sedclearmalw.sh) but it works if i just use it directly via ssh

Comment: The grep is not running in the directory that you want it to run in  since `cd ../public_html` failed. - hence it is not finding anything.

Comment: @terdon The `-i`option in `sed` is where the action happens.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan d'oh! Missed that completely. Of course, thanks.

Comment: @terdon Easily done. It is a GNU-ism, after all. :)

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan no it isn't! It just isn't POSIX, but it's also implemented on [BSD sed](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/sed/), it's not restricted to GNU. Nah, no excuse, I just missed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems is due to the use of a relative path. When `cron` runs a scheduled job, it uses the home directory of the owner as its working directory, e.g., if I schedule a job as the root user, its working directory will be `/root/` (on a Cent OS system).

You should specify the absolute path in your `cd` command. If you’re not running any further commands in your script, you could just run it all in one line:

```
grep -rl '_0xaae8' /full/path/to/public_html/ | xargs sed -i 's/var\s_0xaae8.*//g'
```

Comment: Changing to full path to public_html did it, i also had a typo in my "dummy" data which i use to simulate files containing that keyword.. Thanks for the answer.